# PyArrow version issue

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyarrow

I have installed pyArrow version 7.0.0 and python version is 3.8, but still it is complaining

`ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.15.1 must be installed; however, it was not found.`

Error is thrown at below line

`@pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)`

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You might need to see if the pip that you using is updated too, and if you're runing your code inside of a notebook using EMR or something like that you must to check if there is any kind of virtual env too. Could you provide more info?

Comment: @HiagoReis I am running this as a pyspark job on the cluster. The pip version that i am using is 22.1.2. There is no virtual env.
The line where it is throwing this error is:
@pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

Comment: I see, you have all the needed libs installed in your cluster? When I was having this error some of my libs wheren't updated to the version needed by pandas. In my case was setuptools.